# JQuery: fadeIn() without declaring opacity in CSS?

Tags: jquery

CSS

```
#mobilemenuclosewide {
 display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$( mobilemenuclosewide ).fadeIn( 2000 );
```

When I fade this element in with JQuery, it fades in perfectly. But I thought fadeIn() only brought an element's opacity from 0 to 1? I thought show() was the JQuery method for displaying an element that has display:none in the CSS.

Why does this work when I feel like it shouldn't?

Comment: There are several jQuery methods that can be used to show a hidden element. `.slideDown()` is another.

Comment: From the [relevant jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/): "The [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) method animates the opacity of the matched elements. It is similar to the [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method but that method does not unhide the element and can specify the final opacity level." ... which implies that `.fadeIn()` does unhide the element (as you have pointed out).

Comment: Is fadeIn() designed to unhide an element as well as fade its opacity to 1?

Comment: @5south - [Yes.](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: @JoshCrozier You are the man.